# Regex - escaping '

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a string and extract some values.

Suddenly, I'm stuck with the with symbols here:

Here is some code, to describe my situation:

```
// example string
$string = "@set('var', 'value')";

// regex that I'm using to extract the values
$regex = '@set\((.+),(.+)\)/'

// result that I'm getting
array("'var'", "'value'")

// desired result
array("var", "value")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you wish these to be escaped, whats your approach when displaying the escaped values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are matching any character with `.+` rule. If you don't want quotes to be in the result, avoid them. Rewrited rule:

```
 $regex = "/@set\('([^']+)',\s*'([^']+)'\)/"
```

Comment: This doesn't take the whitespace between the two values into acocunt.

Comment: Updated the rule to fix the whitespace missing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick. You've saved me another hour of frustration :)